# After the Buddha's enlightenment, did he receive any teachings?

Tags: theravada, reference-request, mahayana, sutras

There's not much background to this question. Did the Buddha ever receive a teaching after his enlightenment; a teaching that he accepted and made use of, either his own or another - or perhaps a teaching from another being other than a human.

Please provide sutta references.

I'm asking because of this term commonly found near or at the end of suttas: *'the job has been done, there is nothing more for this world'*

Another way to put it: can one be independent of the teachings? If not, what situations would call forth the remembering and practising of the teachings for an enlightened mind?

Thanks

**ADDITIONAL EDIT:**

In my quest to answer this question I had found a sutta in which the Buddha had asked Venerable Mahacunda to give him a teaching on the enlightenment factors. You can read it [here.](https://suttacentral.net/sn46.16/en/bodhi)

Also, the second part of the question  is answered [here](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/28696/20268) which references this sutta [here.](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn06/sn06.002.than.html)

Comment: The answer to this question -- [Reference request for “the Buddha takes the Dhamma as his superior”](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/28691/254) -- might be a partial answer to the questions in the last paragraph above.

Comment: @ChrisW - yes, it partially answers the question, but I found a sutta where the Buddha had asked one of his disciples for a teaching. It's very interesting to me! I'll update the question soon.

Answer (score 2):

> *I found a sutta where the Buddha had asked one of his disciples for a teaching*

Consider this

> Then Ven. Sariputta addressed the monks: "Friend monks."
>
> "Yes, friend," the monks responded to him.
>
> Ven. Sariputta said: "All those who ask questions of another do so
> from any one of five motivations. Which five?
>
> "One asks a question of another through stupidity & bewilderment. One
> asks a question of another through evil desires & overwhelmed with
> greed. One asks a question of another through contempt. One asks a
> question of another when desiring knowledge. Or one asks a question
> with this thought,[1] 'If, when asked, he answers correctly, well &
> good. If not, then I will answer correctly [for him].'
>
> "All those who ask questions of another do so from any one of these
> five motivations. And as for me, when I ask a question of another,
> it's with this thought: 'If, when asked, he answers correctly, well &
> good. If not, then I will answer correctly [for him].' - AN 5:165

> He whose victory cannot be undone,whose victory no one here approaches, the Buddha, whose range is endless,by what path can you lead the pathless one? - Dhp

Answer (score 0):

The Buddha, being fully enlightened and fully liberated, does not really need any new teachings for spiritual liberation from anyone, for his benefit.

However, he may ask his arahant disciples to provide teachings or elaboration for the benefit of the unenlightened.

An example of this is [SN 12.31](https://suttacentral.net/sn12.31/en/bodhi). It ends with:

> “Good, good, Sāriputta!... (the Buddha repeats here the entire statement
> of the Venerable Sāriputta) ... it is in such a way that the meaning of
> this, stated in brief, should be understood in detail.”

Please also see [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/43390/471). The Buddha denied complete omniscience. He could potentially know and understand all things, but not all at the same time. He only possesses the full knowledge and understanding of spiritual liberation.

With regards to other types of knowledge, for e.g. of science, the Buddha possesses the intellectual capacity to understand them. So, the Buddha can still receive teachings unrelated to spiritual liberation from others.

Comment: [46.16](https://suttacentral.net/sn46.16/en/bodhi) says he asked Venerable Mahacunda for a teaching on the enlightenment factors. If he did it once, he must have done it before. Have I misinterpreted that sutta? Is there another meaning to it?

Comment: @NeuroMax The Buddha wanted Ven. Mahacunda to recite or express his understanding of the enlightenment factors, and then the Buddha, his teacher, approved his recitation or understanding. The Buddha did not learn anything new from Ven. Mahacunda.

Comment: I think one can go further than "does not really need any new teachings for spiritual liberation from anyone" to does not need any teachings at all. He is a Buddha, perfect in behavior & traditions of the Noble One's, he knows everything a Buddha needs to know because he is one and his ranges are limitless. It is said that he even opened up heaven's & hell for all to see ... i think that if someone was to teach a Buddha then the universe wouldn't be able to live with itself, is my conviction.

Comment: @Buddhism Please see [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/43390/471). The Buddha denied complete omniscience. He could potentially know and understand all things, but not all at the same time. He only possesses the full knowledge and understanding of spiritual liberation. With regards to other types of knowledge, for e.g. of science, the Buddha possesses the intellectual capacity to understand them. So, the Buddha can still receive teachings unrelated to spiritual liberation from others.

Comment: You are making a mistake saying that knowing & seeing things simultaneously is the same as having a capacity to understand. Mn90: Great king, I recall making this statement: ‘There is no ascetic or brahmin who knows all and sees all simultaneously: that is not possible.’”.  The Buddha can know & see all things heard, senses or cognized, he can also know the mind of another with his mind. Traditional Theravada holds that he can know anything he directs his mind to albeit not simultaneously. This notion of being capable to understand through instruction is kind of absurd.

Comment: The Blessed One said: “Monks, whatever in this world with its devas, Māras & Brahmās, in this generation with its contemplatives & brahmans, its rulers & commonfolk, is seen, heard, sensed, cognized, attained, sought after, pondered by the intellect: That do I know. Whatever in this world with its devas, Māras & Brahmās, in this generation with its contemplatives & brahmans, its rulers & commonfolk, is seen, heard, sensed, cognized, attained, sought after, pondered by the intellect: That I directly know. - AN 4:58

Comment: @Buddhism What about [MN 71](https://suttacentral.net/mn71/en/sujato)? -  “Sir, I have heard this: ‘The ascetic Gotama claims to be all-knowing and all-seeing, to know and see everything without exception, thus: “Knowledge and vision are constantly and continually present to me, while walking, standing, sleeping, and waking.”’ I trust that those who say this repeat what the Buddha has said, and do not misrepresent him with an untruth? ...
“Vaccha, **those who say this do not repeat what I have said. They misrepresent me with what is false and untrue**.”

Comment: @Buddhism Continuing [MN 71](https://suttacentral.net/mn71/en/sujato) - ‘The ascetic Gotama has the three knowledges.’ Answering like this you would repeat what I have said, and not misrepresent me with an untruth. You would explain in line with my teaching, and there would be no legitimate grounds for rebuke and criticism.”

Comment: I do not say that Buddha knows everything knowing & seeing everything without exception. There is a difference between "everything can be be known" and "everything is known without exception". Therefore i think your followup excerpts are irrelevant as i did not assert that he knows & sees everything without exception.

Comment: Perhaps give an example of what he doesn't know or can't know having directed the mind to it, how to seclude information from someone who can read minds.

Comment: Not that i enjoy pestering you with this but i want to say that i think i understand why you see it otherwise. I guess it is because "knowing all" can be taken to mean understanding the workings of the perception of other beings, 'understanding' as direct seeing for an 4:58, basically taking the sutta definition from sabba sutta and applying it here to 'knowing all'.

Comment: There is this passage as well; 
“Sir, I’m well-known as a charioteer skilled in a chariot’s parts. All the parts are well-known to me. The answer just appears to me on the spot.”

“In the same way, when clever aristocrats, brahmins, householders, or ascetics come to see me with a question already planned, the answer just appears to me on the spot. Why is that? Because the Realized One has clearly comprehended the principle of the teachings, so that the answer just appears to him on the spot.” https://suttacentral.net/mn58/en/sujato i think that this applies to anything a person might plan

Comment: As i see it there is a lot of evidence for Buddha basically being able to answer any question that can be posed to him and that about anything a person can think of. One could explain away the evidence but at some point one has to produce counter evidence as well.

Answer (score 0):

Lord Buddha didn't receive any teachings after his Enlightenment. He spoke with various philosophers, however, and they told him many interesting things, but that doesn't count as "receiving teachings".