# Is it true that no phenomena can be ubiquitous?

Tags: impermanence, dhammas

Sabbe Sankhara Anicca means all conditioned phenomena are impermanent.

However , I was thinking whether any phenomena can be present everywhere even for a short span of time ?

In other words I think , no conditioned phenomena can be ubiquitous because it will give a sense of temporary Self.
One ubiquitous phenomena which comes to my mind is the presence of atom. Everything is made up of atoms except dark matter. Another ubiquitous phenomena is gravity. It seems to present everywhere.This is true for everything and everywhere.

Is it true that no conditioned phenomena can be ubiquitous?
And what will be the Pali or Sanskrit translation for “No conditioned phenomena can be ubiquitous.”?

PS : I think Buddha didn’t say anything about it. However your thoughts are welcome. One reason I asked this question was because an ubiquitous phenomena gives at least a sense of temporary Self.

Answer (score 1):

How about "space"? Because perhaps that's ubiquitous by definition.

But maybe that is, in some way, beyond the limit of consciousness -- see [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/12966/254)

> He cannot, however, know everything simultaneously and must advert to whatever he wishes to know. At MN 90.8 the Buddha says that it is possible to know and see all, though not simultaneously, etc.

---

An English dictionary definition of "phenomenon" is "a fact or situation that is observed to exist or happen" -- if you cannot be conscious of it all at once, that could imply that the observation (and therefore, what's "phenomenal") is in that sense never "ubiquitous".

Answer (score 1):

The internet says:

> ubiquitous
>
> /juːˈbɪkwɪtəs/
>
> adjective
>
> present, appearing, or found everywhere.
>
> "his ubiquitous influence was felt by all the family"

> Omnipresence or ubiquity is the property of being present anywhere and
> everywhere. The term omnipresence is most often used in a religious
> context as an attribute of a deity or supreme being, while the term
> ubiquity is generally used to describe something "existing or being
> everywhere at the same time, constantly encountered, widespread,
> common". Ubiquitous is also used synonymously with other words,
> including: worldwide, universal, global, pervasive, and all over the
> place.
>
> From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia

In SN 22.59, when referring to impermanent phenomena which are also not-self, the Buddha said:

> bhikkhus, any kind of form whatsoever, whether past, future, or
> present, internal or external, **gross or subtle**, inferior or superior,
> far or near, all form should be seen as it really is with correct
> wisdom thus

Something being ubiquitous, such  as atoms, or what the Buddha called 'the elements', does not change the fact of impermanence. There will come a time the Planet Earth ends. Therefore the atoms making up the Earth will end or change their form/structure.

Comment: My hypothesis is that nothing can be omnipresent or ubiquitous. Can you translate “no phenomena can be ubiquitous .”  in Pali ?